# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server - When using TempData

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use `TempData` in my controller so I will be able to save my selected values from my dropdownlists between requests, but this dont work. It's only when I add the TempData code I get this error, so the `SaveProcessView` and `ProcessViewForAdmin` methods works fine without the tempdata code.

I've been searching the web for answers but I can't seem to find any, but it seems like it can't find my SQL Server, which is weird since the database works fine everywhere else on the website. Remote connections is allowed.

I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5363103
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +110
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.]
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection conn, Exception e) +235
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +944
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling) +231
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +199
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +565
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Controller methods:

```
    public ActionResult ProcessViewForAdmin()
    {
        var model = _IGenerateProcessFlowData.UpdateProcessFlowViewModel();
        var modeltemp = TempData["model"] as ProcessViewModel;

        if (modeltemp != null)
        {
            model.SelectedCustomer = modeltemp.SelectedCustomer;
            model.SelectedSeconds = modeltemp.SelectedSeconds;
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveProcessViewForCustomer(ProcessViewModel model)
    {
        TempData["model"] = model;
        _iSlideLogic.ConnectProcessViewAndSlideByMainCustomerName(model.SelectedCustomer, 1, "", model.SelectedSeconds);

        return RedirectToAction("ProcessViewForAdmin");
    }
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="DBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.Overvakning.csdl|res://*/Context.Overvakning.ssdl|res://*/Context.Overvakning.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Ah-XXXXXXXXX.se;initial catalog=ah-XXXXXXXX;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Another developer in my team gets another error when he tries to run the code:

```
  Cannot open database "ASPState" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'XXXXXX'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure now what the problem is. We are missing the ASPstate database.